Hadamard product: derivatives
How to compute the partial derivatives of the following expression
$$
\phi(x,y)=Ax\circ By,
$$
with the Hadamard product $\circ$, where $A(n-2,n)$, $B(n-2,n)$ are the matrices
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
-0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5
\end{array}\right],\quad B=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & -2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\right],
$$
and $x(n,1)$, $y(n,1)$ are the column vectors. Since
$$
Ax\circ By=By\circ Ax,
$$
the expression can be rewritten to the matrix form
$$
\phi(x,y)=diag(By)Ax=diag(Ax)By,
$$
with the partial derivatives
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x} & =diag(By)A,\\
\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial y} & =diag(Ax)B.
\end{align*}
I am not sure, whether the solution is correct. Thanks for your help.
Updated computation:
Consider
$$
\phi_{i}(x,y)=0.5(-x_{i}+x_{i+2})(y_{i}-2y_{i+1}+y_{i+2}),
$$
the partial derivatives have the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\phi_{i}(x,y)}{\partial x_{j}} & =-0.5(y_{j}-2y_{j+1}+y_{j+2}).\\
\frac{\partial\phi_{i}(x,y)}{\partial x_{j+1}} & =0,\\
\frac{\partial\phi_{i}(x,y)}{\partial x_{j+2}} & =0.5(y_{j}-2y_{j+1}+y_{j+2}),\\
\frac{\partial\phi_{i}(x,y)}{\partial x_{i+3}} & =0,\\
\frac{\partial\phi_{i}(x,y)}{\partial x_{i+3}} & =0,\\
\cdots & \cdots
\end{align*}
and represent elements of $A$. Hence, the above-mentioned partial derivatives should be OK...

@ Semiclassical: Thanks, corrected + solution updated.
